# Understanding why a substance cannot be at $0K$

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, low-temperature-physics

I am trying to understand why it is that a substance cannot have a temperature of exactly 0K. My text book's explanation is that since internal energy is the sum of the kinetic energies of the molecules in the substance and the potential energy in the electrostatic forces between them, and since there will always be electrostatic forces between atoms in a substance, the substance will always have some internal energy. However, I don't see how not being able to have zero internal energy corresponds to not being able to have a temperature of 0K. Is this because temperature is more related to internal energy (of which the kinetic energies of the molecules is a part), rather than being dependent only on just the kinetic energies of the atoms?

Comment: Your book is wrong. Temperature is not energy, certainly not at low temperatures where quantum effects become important.

Comment: @Pieter It doesn't seem the book is equating temperature and energy, based on second sentence of the post. It seems the OP is equating temperature and energy, based on the third paragraph of the post. It looks like the OP is misinterpreting the book.

Comment: In Statistical Physics temperature is related to the number of accessible micro states of the system. In quantum theory fluctuation must be considered. Therefore, it would help, if you could tell us from which perspective you like to understand the concept of temperature.

Answer (score 1):

In physics, there is nothing against a substance having a temperature of 0 K. It is an assumption that is often made in theory. But there is no way that one can *cool* a substance from a finite temperature to absolute zero.

One could present different arguments, this is about a recent article:
https://www.newscientist.com/article/2124597-cooling-to-absolute-zero-mathematically-outlawed-after-a-century/